# ¿Como difieren "ir _ando" y "estar _ando"?

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales

Hay una forma del verbo que termina en *-ndo*, como *caminando* o *durmiendo*.  Yo pienso que esta forma se llama el "participio progresivo".

Entiendo como se usa *estar* con el progresivo, por ejemplo:

> Estoy pensando.

Pero hace poco me encontré una forma semejante con *ir* como:

> Voy cambiando.

Por su contexto, confío (o solo imagino) que la de arriba esta formada bien.

**¿Como difieren los sentidos de *ir _ando* y *estar _ando*?**

Answer (score 5):

Esa forma se llama "gerundio". En español solo existe un participio, el de pasado (el participio de presente solo tiene restos fosilizados del latín; puedes leer más [aquí](http://www.delcastellano.com/2010/07/29/participio-de-presente-activo-espanol-amante-amado/)).

La forma con "ir" es una perífrasis verbal que puede significar varias cosas, dependiendo del contexto (deberías haber dado algún contexto). En general, puede ser una acción progresiva que se repite en el tiempo, o que toma mucho tiempo para realizarse (es decir, se extiende en el tiempo una sola acción).

Por supuesto, "ir andando" puede ser simplemente que esa persona va caminando, es decir, "andando" simplemente indica el modo en el que esa persona va al lugar de destino.